# Slow GroupAggregate in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, group-by

In PostgreSQL 9.2, I have a table of items that are being rated by users:

```
   id   | userid | itemid |    rating     |      timestamp      |      !update_time
--------+--------+--------+---------------+---------------------+------------------------
 522241 | 3991   | 6887   |  0.1111111111 | 2005-06-20 03:13:56 | 2013-10-11 17:50:24.545
 522242 | 3991   | 6934   |  0.1111111111 | 2005-04-05 02:25:21 | 2013-10-11 17:50:24.545
 522243 | 3991   | 6936   | -0.1111111111 | 2005-03-31 03:17:25 | 2013-10-11 17:50:24.545
 522244 | 3991   | 6942   | -0.3333333333 | 2005-03-24 04:38:02 | 2013-10-11 17:50:24.545
 522245 | 3991   | 6951   | -0.5555555556 | 2005-06-20 03:15:35 | 2013-10-11 17:50:24.545
 ...    | ...    | ...    | ...           | ...                 | ...
```

I want to perform a very simple query: for each user, select the total number of ratings in the database.

I'm using the following straightforward approach:

```
SELECT userid, COUNT(*) AS rcount
FROM ratings
GROUP BY userid
```

The table contains 10M records. The query takes... well, about 2 or 3 minutes. Honestly, I'm not satisfied with that, and I believe that 10M is not so large number for the query to take so long. (Or is it..??)

Henceforth, I asked PostgreSQL to show me the execution plan:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT userid, COUNT(*) AS rcount
FROM ratings
GROUP BY userid
```

This results in:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=1756177.54..1831423.30 rows=24535 width=5)
  ->  Sort  (cost=1756177.54..1781177.68 rows=10000054 width=5)
      Sort Key: userid
      ->  Seq Scan on ratings  (cost=0.00..183334.54 rows=10000054 width=5)
```

I read this as follows: Firstly, the whole table is read from the disk (seq scan). Secondly, it is sorted by userid in `n*log(n)` (sort). Finally, the sorted table is read row-by-row and aggregated in linear time. Well, not exactly the optimal algorithm I think, if I were to implement it by myself, I would use a hash table and build the result in the first pass. Never mind.

It seems that it is the sorting by `userid` which takes so long. So added an index:

```
CREATE INDEX ratings_userid_index ON ratings (userid)
```

Unfortunately, this didn't help and the performance remained the same. I definitely do not consider myself an advanced user and I believe I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. However, this is where I got stuck. I would appreciate any ideas how to make the query execute in reasonable time. One more note: PostgreSQL worker process utilizes 100 % of one of my CPU cores during the execution, suggesting that disk access is not the main bottleneck.

**EDIT**

As requested by @a_horse_with_no_name. Wow, quite advanced for me:

```
EXPLAIN (analyze on, buffers on, verbose on)
SELECT userid,COUNT(userid) AS rcount
FROM movielens_10m.ratings
GROUP BY userId
```

Outputs:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=1756177.54..1831423.30 rows=24535 width=5) (actual time=110666.899..127168.304 rows=69878 loops=1)
  Output: userid, count(userid)
  Buffers: shared hit=906 read=82433, temp read=19358 written=19358
  ->  Sort  (cost=1756177.54..1781177.68 rows=10000054 width=5) (actual time=110666.838..125180.683 rows=10000054 loops=1)
        Output: userid
        Sort Key: ratings.userid
        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 154840kB
        Buffers: shared hit=906 read=82433, temp read=19358 written=19358
        ->  Seq Scan on movielens_10m.ratings  (cost=0.00..183334.54 rows=10000054 width=5) (actual time=0.019..2889.583 rows=10000054 loops=1)
              Output: userid
              Buffers: shared hit=901 read=82433
Total runtime: 127193.524 ms
```

**EDIT 2**

@a_horse_with_no_name's comment solved the problem. I feel happy to share my findings:

```
SET work_mem = '1MB';
EXPLAIN SELECT userid,COUNT(userid) AS rcount
FROM movielens_10m.ratings
GROUP BY userId
```

produces the same as above:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=1756177.54..1831423.30 rows=24535 width=5)
  ->  Sort  (cost=1756177.54..1781177.68 rows=10000054 width=5)
      Sort Key: userid
      ->  Seq Scan on ratings  (cost=0.00..183334.54 rows=10000054 width=5)
```

However,

```
SET work_mem = '10MB';
EXPLAIN SELECT userid,COUNT(userid) AS rcount
FROM movielens_10m.ratings
GROUP BY userId
```

gives

```
HashAggregate  (cost=233334.81..233580.16 rows=24535 width=5)
  ->  Seq Scan on ratings  (cost=0.00..183334.54 rows=10000054 width=5)
```

The query now only takes about 3.5 seconds to complete.

Comment: Please post the output of `explain (analyze on, buffers on, verbose on) .. `

Comment: One thing you might consider is placing this query into a `materialized view` and (occasionally) updating the view as part of your rating insertion/triggering. That is, caching this query.

Comment: Your main problem is not the seq scan, it's the sort which is done on disk. You can try `set work_mem = '250MB'` (or even higher) before running the query - if you have enough memory that is.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Excellent, exactly solves the problem! Actually, even 10 MB is enough in my case. If I use ``set work_mem = '1MB'``, then the plan is GroupAggregate using sort as I posted. But when I use ``set work_mem = '10MB'``, then the plan changes to HashAggregate. Now it makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 3):

Consider how your query could possibly return a result... You could build a variable-length hash and create/increment its values; or you could sort all rows by userid and count. Computationally, the latter option is cheaper. That is what Postgres does.

Then consider *how* to sort the data, taking disk IO into account. One option is to open disk pages A, B, C, D, etc., and then sorting rows by userid in memory. In other words, seq scan followed by a sort. The other option, called an index scan, would be to pull rows in order by using an index: visit page B, then D, then A, then B again, A again, C, ad nausea.

An index scan is efficient when pulling a handful of rows in order; not so much to fetch many rows in order — let alone all rows in order. As such, the plan you're getting is the optimal one:

1. Plough throw all rows (seq scan)
2. Sort rows to group by criteria
3. Count rows by criteria

Trouble is, you're sorting roughly 10 million rows in order to count them by userid. Nothing will make things faster short of investing in more RAM and super fast SSDs.

You *can*, however, avoid this query altogether. Either:

- Count ratings for the handful of users that you actually *need* — using a where clause — instead of pulling the entire set; or
- Add a ratings_count field to your users table and use triggers on ratings to maintain the count.
- Use a materialized view, if the precise count is less relevant than having a vague idea of it.

Comment: Pardon my doubts, but I don't see why the hash table approach is computationally suboptimal. Actually, that is what I'm planning to do if I won't solve the problem at the PostgreSQL level. I would almost guarantee that I'll be faster than 2 minutes...

Comment: @Tregoreg: I'm guessing there are considerations such as "by sorting rows, you build the set incrementally and avoid lookups" as well as "by sorting rows, we don't risk that the hash is too large to fit in memory". I'd advise that you take your doubts to the pg-hackers list, though. Tom Lane will probably give you the precise reason why they approach things this way rather than the other.

Comment: If I reduce the query to ``SELECT userid FROM ratings``, it only takes about 3 seconds. Still not perfect, and I like both the solutions you suggest, but, I consider it reasonable. Just from curiosity, I would like to know whether I could do better in PostgreSQL with the original query. Because if I can't, I'll completely avoid such queries in future and will try to move as much application logic outside SQL as possible.

Comment: Yep, I would understand the concerns about memory consumptions, especially for tables with billions of rows. Thanks for clear explanation anyway, it seems you are absolutely right -- the PostgreSQL worker reads 850 MB and writes 150 MB from disk, yet consumes only 6 MB or RAM.

Comment: The query plan you're getting by doing `select userid from ratings` skips the sorting and counting, so you're basically measuring how long it takes to plow through the entire table. Best I'm aware, you can't do better than your query plan for that particular query. Naturally, it'll be a completely different story if you actually need a handful of users and run: `select userid, count(*) from ratings where id in (1,2,3,4)`. An index on `ratings (userid)` then becomes useful should make the query very fast. For the top raters, an index on `users (ratings_count)` would be in order.

Comment: That being said, and as horse mentioned in the comments, you could increase the memory Postgres is allowed to use if you've plenty to spare, so as to avoid sorting on disk. It will result in a significant speed boost. But I'm still puzzled that you'd want to plow through 10M rows in the first place: you probably have some kind of sort/limit/offset criteria in practice, to paginate the data. If so, push it down to the database layer, in order to reduce the amount of rows Postgres is manipulating.

Comment: See my post in reply to horse. As I increase the working memory, the plan is changed and the hash-table based aggregation as we discussed is really used!

Answer (score 0):

Try like below, because `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(userid)` makes a lot of difference.

```
SELECT userid, COUNT(userid) AS rcount
FROM ratings
GROUP BY userid
```

Comment: I've already tried that, too. Sadly, it makes no difference. Still 2 minutes, as well as the exact same estimated numbers in the execution plan.

Comment: @Tregoreg you have any join to ratings table? or you are trying with the same query which you have posted here?

Comment: I'm using the exact same query as in this post. Actually, I was doing much more complicated query with joins at first, but this is the "bottlenecking kernel" I successfully isolated from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run 'VACUUM ANALYZE ratings' to update data Statics, so the optimizer can choose a better scenario to execute SQL.